# Adding .value (or .text) from textbox to cell without overwriting AND in a new line

Tags: vba, excel

This sends data from the form textbox to the appropriate cell without overwriting the cell contents:

```
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23) & "whatever the textbox contains"
```

The problem I'm having is that this just concatenates the new and the old data and I need each new entry to be separated in a new line. I've tried this:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value & _
    Application.SendKeys("%{ENTER}") & MASCACIncomingRef.Value
```

but on compiling I'm missing something to make the sendkey work. I couldn't find any posts with a solution...

I need to ensure each entry is in a new line within the cell because I'm using the contents of that cell to show in another part of the form as a kind of table (don't ask), so I need each new value added to the cell to be on below or on top of the last value already in the cell. Could anyone help?

Comment: Replace `Application.SendKeys("%{ENTER}")` by `vbLf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a line break in a cell add `Chr(10)` or `vbLf` like:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Text = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23) & Chr(10) & "whatever the textbox contains"
```